# How to deal with memory management when initializing NSArray from C array

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

I am initializing an NSArray using a C array of objects I dynamically create:

```
MyClass *initArray [dynamicSize];

for (NSUInteger i=0; i<dynamicSize; i++) {
   initArray [i] = [[MyClass alloc] initWithSomthingDependingOn: i];
}
// At this point, initArray contains objects with retainCount == 1

classObjectArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:initArray count:dynamicSize];
// And... at this point, retainCount == 2
```

My problem/doubt is about how to deal with memory management in this situation. My understanding is that I should be releasing all the objects once to keep retainCount == 1, for I will only keep one reference to them (initArray will disappear after the function returns)... but I find it inefficient having to iterate again through the array just to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** *to avoid confusing code example modified swapping* `initExpresion (i)` *to* `[[MyClass alloc] initWith... ]` *which better represents the nature of the problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Any suggestions?

Yes.

## Do not call retainCount

It is misleading at best and flat out useless most of the time.

As Jonathan said, only balance retains that you cause via the various methods listed.   That is, **treat the retain count like a delta**.  *If you increase it, you must decrease it.*

In this specific case, the "`initExpression()`" is either returning a retained or autoreleased object.  You can't tell via `retainCount` since `autorelease` doesn't immediately decrement that count (it is, effectively, a delayed `release`).

(No, `initExpression()` didn't confuse the question or this answer -- `retainCount` is useless for "detecting" an autoreleased object.)

In a comment, you said:

> I am concerned about the
>   performance impact of either
>   autoreleasing the objects or iterating
>   again through the array to send a
>   release message to all of the objects.

Concerned because you measured a problem or because it seems like it might be an issue?

Don't waste time fixing performance problems that haven't been quantified.  It is exceedingly unlikely that the objects being either manually released or autoreleased is going to be a problem in that context.   It can happen, but not unless you have Ns of thousands of objects (at which point you might have a memory issue in and of itself) or are calling through this code many times.

Jonathan's suggestion of skipping the C array entirely is a good one!

Comment: Hi Bbum, thanks for your reply. I am using retainCount as a learning tool to understand how memory management works with cocoa framework (catching up with programming from C++ after maaany years). I think my pseudo-naming `initExpresion()` trying to make code nicer is actually confusing things up so I will edit my original question just in case it proves useful to others (hope you guys don't mind).  And well... I guess I should just calm down on performance and just make things simple using NS containers. Thx.

Comment: Can't say it enough;  do **not** use `retainCount`.  Not as a learning tool, not as a debugging tool, and not in production.  As this very case shows, it is misleading as a learning tool.  `initExpression()` didn't confuse things at all.

Comment: Also -- you can't effectively optimize code without analyzing & quantifying first.  You are definitely prematurely optimizing and, yes, backing off that stance will make for a much more productive coding experience!

Answer (score 0):

`initExpression()` should be autoreleasing its resultant objects since its name does not begin with `retain`, `create`, `new`, `copy`, or `alloc`. If it does, the problem goes away.

If the objects it returns are not autoreleased, then it is the caller's (your) responsibility to either `releas` or `autorelease` those objects after using them.

**Edit:** Of course, you could just skip the C array and use an `NSMutableArray` with a capacity of `dynamicSize`:

```
NSMutableArray *classObjectArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: dynamicSize];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < dynamicSize; i++) {
    id myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init...];
    if (myObject) {
        [classObjectArray addObject: myObject];
        [myObject release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank your for your prompt answer... unfortunately, initExpression() was just a name made for the example, the fact is that it is more like a [[MyClass alloc] initWith... ] expresion. I do understand I am responsible for releasing the objects, but I am concerned about the performance impact of either autoreleasing the objects or iterating again through the array to send a release message to all of the objects.

Comment: Well, since those are your only options, you'll have to pick one or the other; either `autorelease` them all or `release` them all. Otherwise you'll leak them.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have to confess that I have a certain distrust on the performance implications of `autorelease`, ungrounded perhaps. However, it would really strike me if you told me it is not significantly more efficient to work with a C array instead of a `NSMutableArray`... unless of course it is more efficient building a `NSArray` based on a `NSMutableArray` instead than based on a C array. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: C arrays will be faster than `NSMutableArray`.  Sure.  But does it matter?  Almost assuredly not and any claims otherwise are complete hogwash without a significant body of performance analysis evidence indicating a real problem!

Comment: Exactly, @bbum — @Victor, write clean, functioning code first. Only then worry about optimizing, and even then only when you can actually prove it to be too slow for your needs. :)